# Convert image format in series with Python

Tags: python, for-loop, python-imaging-library, jpeg, bmp

sorry for my trivial question, but I'm new to Python.

I'm trying to convert a series of `JPEG` images to `BMP` format and resize it.
I managed to get the procedure for a single image, but now I can not automate the process so that the conversion happens in sequence.
this is my script

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open("C:/Users/***/Documents/images/1.jpg")
new_img = img.resize((320,240))
new_img.save("C:/Users/***/Documents/immages_bmp/1.bmp")
```

The images are progressively renamed from 1 to 10000.
Does anyone know how to help me implement a for loop to automate the process?
Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
from PIL import Image
from glob import glob
import os
myDir = '/Users/me/pictures'
pic_list = glob(myDir + os.sep + '*' + '.jpg')

for pic in pic_list:
  #resize, use a string replace to name new bmps
  img = Image.open(pic)
  new_img = img.resize((320,240))
  newName = pic.replace(".jpg",".bmp")
  new_img.save(newName)
```

Should catch all the images regardless as to their naming convention, and will allow you to edit the list of names before you resize them (or not).

Comment: thanks, sorry but if I want to save the new images in a different folder, how should I do?

Comment: Is the name of your folder consistent? Something like: **newName = newName.replace("jpgFolder","bmpFolder")** (just after newName is first assigned).

Comment: And make sure you have the folders (directories) already created before you run the program.